# How to Remove number from Extension with string?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to remove number from Extension with string in C#.

> **For Example : "Url1234.pdf" I want the last answer looks like "Url.pdf"**

Thank you for your Contribution

```
  var fileName = "";
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName); //Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                DBConnect.OpenDB();
                DBConnect.DbSelect("select MAX(ID) as ID from tblFileUpload");
                if(DBConnect.dr.Read())
                {
                    fileName += DBConnect.dr["ID"].ToString();
                }
                DBConnect.CloseDB();
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/File/"), fileName+extension);
                new FileUploadLayer().save("aa", fileName, file.ContentLength);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                UploadFile("aa");
            }
```

I save a file with the extension(.pdf). That file name has numbers also.(Url1234.pdf).So, when i call it back i need to remove those numbers and only need the string part (Url.pdf).

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: You might find the class [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) interesting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use regex as shown or a simple LINQ query, i'd also recommend `System.IO.Path`:

```
string originalPath = "Url1234.pdf";
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(originalPath);              // in this case ""
string extension = Path.GetExtension(originalPath);            // .pdf
string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalPath);    // Url1234
string newFn = String.Concat(fn.Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c))); // Url
string newPath = Path.Combine(dir, newFn + extension);         // Url.pdf
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Regex to replace numbers with empty string:

```
var result1 = Regex.Replace("Url1234.pdf", @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
```

Add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`